# Print Datagrid in ASP.NET using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My question is how to print data of datagrid in asp.net using vb.net. Data is in the form of rows and columns, stored in datagrid. I want to print the data using vb.net. I searched for some built-in component but couldn't find the exact one. Although, printdocument is only for windows form applications.

Can you please help me out!

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebForms ReportViewer Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337091.aspx). If you use a `DataSet` to populate your datagrid you can set it as a `ReportSource` in a rdlc file and display it in a `ReportViewer`.

Comment: Thanks!
let me try it.